# Sorting and Adding to a table based on conditions

Tags: mysql

Table 1 has 4 columns and the mock data looks like this...

```
MASTER_ID  SUB_ID  DESC   Percent
1234       ABC     TEXT   80
1234       XYZ     TEXT2  20
1234       XYZ     TEXT4  30
9876       XYZ     TEXT2  20
9876       XYZ     TEXT5  10
9876       ABC     TEXT1  20
```

Table 2 contains the distinct values for each MASTER_ID's DESC which is column 3 of table 1 ....

```
MASTER_ID  DESC
1234       TEXT
1234       TEXT2
1234       TEXT4
9876       TEXT2
9876       TEXT5
9876       TEXT1
```

I need to look through TABLE1 and find which DESC are missing for each SUB_ID for each specific MASTER_ID. Each MASTER_ID has nothing to do with the other... which means that I should not see descriptions that do not exist in the MASTER_PLAN. For example MASTER_ID 9876 has a DESC of TEXT5. This DESC should only appear in MASTER_ID's 9876 DESC's. The SUB_ID can exist in different MASTER_ID. But as stated before each MASTER_ID should be thought of as stand alone.

the final table should look like this....

```
MASTER_ID  SUB_ID  DESC   Percent
1234       ABC     TEXT    80
1234       ABC     TEXT2   0
1234       ABC     TEXT4   0
1234       XYZ     TEXT2   20
1234       XYZ     TEXT4   30
1234       XYZ     TEXT    0
9876       XYZ     TEXT2   20
9876       XYZ     TEXT5   10
9876       XYZ     TEXT1   0
9876       ABC     TEXT1   20
9876       ABC     TEXT2   0
9876       ABC     TEXT5   0
```

Comment: Please label the columns. Also, what is MASTER_PLAN?

Comment: sorry MASTER_PLAN should be MASTER_ID... COL1 is MASTER_ID, COL2 is SUB_ID, COL3 is DESC, COL4 is percent. For table 2 it just has 2 columns... COL1 is MASTER_ID and COL2 is DESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below  query

```
select t3.master_id, t3.sub_id, t3.Desc1, case when t4.percentage is null then 0 else t4.percentage end percentage
from
    (select  distinct t1.master_id, sub_id, t2.Desc1
    from table1 t1
    cross join table2 t2
    where t1.master_id = t2.master_id) t3    
left join table1 t4 
 on t4.master_id = t3.master_id 
  and t3.sub_id = t4.sub_id 
  and t3.desc1 = t4.desc1
```

the above query give me the below result

[image]

Hope this should help you out.